# How to check if all the values in a row/column of a Numpy array are equal to some specific value? AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tic-tac-toe

I am programming TicTacToe game using Numpy and Pandas dataframe, however, the function which checks if all the values in a column are equal to 'X', does not seem to work, because of the error below. Does anyone know how to check if all the values in a column are equal to X, or better check the columns, rows, and diagonals in one function?

File "c:...", line 46, in win1
if ('X' == a).all(): return ('X' == a).all()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'

```
def win1(board):
    for i in column_names:
        a = np.array(board[i])
        if ('X' == a).all(): return ('X' == a).all()
```

```
board = np.array([ [0, 0, 0], 
                   [0, 0, 0], 
                   [0, 0, 0], ])

column_names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
row_names    = ['1', '2', '3']
board = pd.DataFrame(board, columns=column_names, index=row_names)
```

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: maybe `np.all`? Also, you can just return "True" if the condition is met. Or directly return the condition's output, without any "if"...

Comment: That does not seem to work.

Comment: a = np.array(board[i])
return np.all((a == 'X'))

Comment: Your `'X' == a` is already a simple boolean, a True or False.  It isn't an array.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to understand why the error comes up by including:

```
y=(a=="X")
print(y)
```

Comment: The original function is to check if all the values in the column are the same and it works and look like the one below:
```
if (a[0] == a).all(): return (a[0]== a).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully get you going:
It will calculate if all values in the column are equal to X

```py
import pandas as pd

def win1(board):
    for col in board.columns:
        if (board[col] == 'X').all():
            print(f"Column {col} : All values equal to X")
        else:
            print(f"Column {col} : Some values NOT equal to X")

board = np.array([ [0, 'X', 0], 
                   [0, 'X', 'X'], 
                   [0, 'X', 0], ])

column_names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
row_names    = ['1', '2', '3']
board = pd.DataFrame(board, columns=column_names, index=row_names)

# Check each column for a win
win1(board)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Column a : Some values NOT equal to X
Column b : All values equal to X
Column c : Some values NOT equal to X
```